# Emacs Org-mode: Deriving a property value from another property's value

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Suppose I have a these properties defined:

```
:PROPERTIES:
:a: 1
:b: 2
:END:
```

How do I define a property c such that the value is the sum of the value of property `a` and the value of property `b`? I have tried `:c: (+ a b)` but the value of c is just the string `"(+ a b)"`.

Is it possible to define a property in this way or do I have to have a code-block that is then evaluated? (Using the Properties API for instance)

Answer (score 1):

You could define a code block which executes on export, using the [Property API](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-the-Property-API.html):

```
* Code

#+NAME: PropertyCalculator
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
  (let* ( (rootval (string-to-number (org-entry-get nil "root")))
       (squareval (number-to-string (* rootval rootval))) )
    (org-entry-put nil "square" squareval)
    )
#+END_SRC

* Content
** Property Data
:PROPERTIES:
:root:     2
:square:   5
:END:

#+CALL: PropertyCalculator()
```

This would leave any existing entry in place in the buffer, but overwrite in the export.

You could also correct in-buffer with (org-babel-load-file).